# Map not displaying with Google Maps API android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am installing the Google Maps API on my app. I have everything running and can launch the Google Maps Activity, but the Map doesn't display. It just shows a grid that you can zoom in and out on.

```
    package com.fotolife.app;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class Map extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);


    }


}
```

^ that is my Map.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="I Took this out for security reasons, but it works."
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

^ Here is my map.xml

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you set internet permission in AndroidMenifest.xml file

Comment: Yes. I have this: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: and <uses-library android:required="true" 
  android:name="com.google.android.maps">
</uses-library>  in menifest

Comment: I added the android:required="true" but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: is the any other website is working on device/emulator which ever you are using for testing. just check one or two website on mobile browser to check is internet is there or not

Comment: It is. I have a button linked up to the website homepage, and it loads whenever I click on it.

Comment: Then sorry i have no other point left for guessing error.

Comment: Most of the times it doesn't work because of the apiKey. Are you sure it's this apps map key?

Comment: Ok, well I just generated another API key. I signed my app and stored it on my desktop (not in the same place as my source code). It says that I can use the API key with any app that has the same certificate, but I don't know how to register my app with this certificate.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Google Maps Android API v2 that's probably the reason why your project is not working. To get this working you must go through the following steps:

**Download and configure Google Play Services from SDK manager**

Google Play Services are part of the extras of Android's SDK. You can found it in the extras section.

**Add google play services lib JAR to your project build path**

The lib JAR is installed in the path

```
$ANDROIDSDK_HOME/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs
```

**Get an API key using Google APIs Console**

You may generate a SHA1 fingerprint for debug purposes using your OS console by issuing the command:

```
$ keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android
```

In the Google APIs Console go to API Access and in the right pane chose "Create new Android key...". Then put the SHA1 fingerprint in the textbox followed by a semicolon and your project's package name.

**Specify permission settings in your project's manifest file**

Put the following inside manifest tag in your application manifest file (replace com.example with your project's package name):

```
  <permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

  <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
```

**Specify the API key generated from API Console in your project's manifest file**

Put this as the last element before closing the application tag

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="your api key goes here"/>
```

**Add a map to your project**

main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Main.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

**Run your application**

You should get everything working.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this worked for me:

Remember where you got your api-key? https://code.google.com/apis/console , go there and under Key for Android apps (with certificates) press edit allowed android apps.

In my case the fingerprint refered to an old package in a different project so i just went to the cmd console and got my new fingerprint and typed in my current package name after it an BINGO.