# Android blank map

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to use Map Api v2 for few days but didn't have any success. Here is my code:

My HelloGoogleActivity.java:

```
package com.example.hellogooglemap;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class HelloGoogleActivity extends MapActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_hello_google);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My HelloGoogleMap.Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hellogooglemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.hellogooglemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.hellogooglemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="XXXXXyCWfP6QJkMxpQjITsn3IVYT1J_t8UxMohU" />

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hellogooglemap.HelloGoogleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My fragment_hello_google.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyCWfP6QJkMxpQjITsn3IVYT1J_t8UxMohU"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

And my activity_hello_google.xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hellogooglemap.HelloGoogleActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

When I ran this application I got a blank map like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7H4G.jpg

and i have checked several time my apiKey.

So what should I do ?

Comment: You are missing `<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in your manifest..

Comment: Please post your Logcat..

Comment: why are you using mapview???use fragment instead..

Comment: Check this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) for that..

Comment: See the answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408315/map-not-displaying-with-google-maps-api-android) too..Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395809/why-does-mapview-show-grey-tiles-and-not-the-map) too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MapView, you need to implement this in your `onCreate()` method or in `onResume()`.

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(Activity);
yourMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```